# Freestyle On Images

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, image, freestyle

I recently found out about Blender Render's Freestyle option to add stylized lines on a rendered model. It's really neat to see, but I was wondering if it's possible for these lines to affect PNG images (with transparent backgrounds).

For example, if I had an image of a sphere with a transparent background would a line follow the outer line of the PNG sphere and not the mesh the image was applied to?

Comment: As far as I know freestyle is a geometry based stroke rendering engine, that means it will only take actual blender mesh geometry into account, transparency and alpha maps are not supported as far as I know. Even face to face intersections don't generate any strokes if there is no explicit edge there.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. No matter I suppose; I can do that sort of thing in GIMP instead.